# How to solve Django form attribute not working

Tags: django, django-forms, ckeditor

All form attributes work fine, except on textarea. This is my code:

```
# forms.py
class VineyardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vineyard
        fields = [
            "name", "text", "wine_rg", "wines", "size", "grapes",
            "owner", "visits", "region", "regions", "cover"
        ]
        labels = {
            "name": "Vineyard or Property Name",
            "text": "Vineyard Description and Information",
            "wine_rg": "Wine Region and Country",
        }
        widgets = {
            "name": forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Name of your vineyard..."}),
            "text": forms.Textarea(attrs={"placeholder": "something"}),
            "wine_rg": forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Where is your vineyard located: region and country..."}),
        }
```

When I look into the page inspector, I see this code:
[image]

I think the problem is because I'm using ckeditor. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RichTextFormField` in the `django-ckeditor` package is poorly coded, and overwrites any update made with the `widgets` option:

```py
class RichTextFormField(forms.fields.CharField):

    def __init__(self, config_name='default', extra_plugins=None, external_plugin_resources=None, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'widget': CKEditorWidget(config_name=config_name, extra_plugins=extra_plugins,
                                                external_plugin_resources=external_plugin_resources)})
        super(RichTextFormField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, you can update the widget attrs in the `ModelForm` constructor:

```py
class VineyardForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(VineyardForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.fields['text'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = "something"
```